# Does the "Conditioning" perk improve sneak and stamina?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a warrior/mage build, and I am specializing in heavy armor. I'm doing this because I tend to die easy and light armor doesn't sound like enough protection (despite what others say).

I was wondering: if I get the *Conditioning* perk, will this help with my sneak and stamina?

Comment: if you go get the bonus from the steed stone, your heavy armor will no longer weigh anything, thus making it way better than light armor.

Comment: Here are some related questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35024/what-advantages-do-the-different-armor-types-provide  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/does-the-steed-stone-boost-sneaking  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36079/can-you-sneak-well-with-heavy-armor-compared-to-light-or-is-there-no-difference  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36058/can-i-take-off-my-clothes-and-hide-in-the-dark

Comment: @yx.if I would do that would I be losing anything special since the warrior stone wouldnt be active anymore?

Comment: your combat skills will no longer get the 20% faster increase bonus that you currently get from the warrior stone

Answer (score 8):

70 heavy armor (required for Conditioning) is a long way away.  What you really want to solve the sneaking issue is the Muffled Movement perk at 30 sneak (50% noise from armor) and the Muffle spell from illusion.

The survival issue is simple - don't dual wield.  Add a shield and you will live.  Blocking is a huge damage reduction, but even when you don't block the shield adds armor!

Stamina isn't a big deal if you spend a handful of level ups on it and get the Restoration(40) perk - Respite (Healing spells also restore stamina).

Answer (score 2):

It will help your stamina, thats for sure. I've got the perk and I can run for a long time without getting exhausted, before the perk I could only sprint for a few seconds. As for sneaking Im not sure, since my sneaking is only level 30. I get caught easily but I do so too with light armor and sneak bonusses.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The stamina effect of armor is based on its weight, so getting conditioning will mean that your stamina decreases much slower while sprinting.

Sneak impact of armor is based on two things, weight and noise.  So getting conditioning will definitely help by reducing the weight.  From there, you will want to get Muffle as mentioned by David to make your armor even stealthier.

Answer (score 0):

The conditioning perk makes to where you aren't even wearing armor when you sneak. That means that it's even better then wearing light armor when the perk is activated. I've gotten the perk before, and honestly it's debatable in my opinion if it was even intended because it basically makes you a master at sneaking.