# Why can't I kill stealthily?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 100 sneak with all perks excluding the left branch (however, I have tried it with all the left branch perks as well). I'm currently at Knifepoint Ridge, on a quest to stealthily kill all the bandits. Although it's not necessary to kill the bandits stealthily, I choose to do so because I'm a stealth character.

The problem is that whenever I sneak up behind a bandit and cut his/her throat stealthily with muffled boots, stealth rings and necklaces with 100 sneak the sleeping/awake bandits still manage to 'hear' something and say "What was that?" or something along those lines and follows up by detecting me. This has never seemed to happen before. Any advice?

Comment: By any chance did you start using a weapon other than a dagger? Daggers are silent. Others melee weapons are not and this maybe alerting the other bandits.

Comment: User never returned to answer important question about their weapon choice: closing as "unclear" until they drop by again, to stop people from submitting random guesses as answers.

Answer (score 13):

1. Non-dagger weapons are not silent. If you are using a sword, they are hearing you.
2. Do you have a follower? They are notoriously loud.
3. There's a chance that the victim dropped a large, metal item (weapon, shield, etc) that landed somewhere unfortunate and skidded along the ground noisily. I can't imagine this is the case every time, though.

Comment: Are you sure that if you do perform a one hit finishing move even swords are not 'silent' as well?

Comment: @Emanuele Almost positive. I'd be interested to see evidence to the contrary, but as far as I know, swords are not silent.

Comment: I'll try with my rogue as soon as I have some time... any suggested location to test this?

Comment: @Emanuele Nothing comes directly to mind. A generic bandit cave might be ok.

Comment: Bows (if one shot) and daggers are silent, nothing else is, and it's a good idea to have a stealth Armour set (Thieves Guild/Nightingale/Dark Brotherhood).

Comment: @desaivv that's my experience as well.

Answer (score 3):

Are you fighting Forsworn? They have heightened senses and are harder to sneak kill than other human characters.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're wearing equipment that's been enchanted by muffle. Also be cognizant of the shadows. Walking onto any surface with light reduces your chance to successfully sneak on a NPC. Sometimes even the slightest inconsistencies can easily cause detection. Walking over pressure plates, weapons, or any miscellaneous objects are all ways of making noise. As a fellow Nightingale, walk with the shadows.

Comment: If his sneak perk is maxed out, he should be able successfully perform sneak attacks on a NPC. I can't think of any other solution besides having a follower that would trigger detection.

Comment: I completely forgot about that! Heavy armor could definitely be the issue. And not a problem, I really appreciate the edit @desaivv

Answer (score 0):

Silly question, but you should use Light Armor(5/5), Muffle Spell (but your boots already provide it), daggers to avoid making noise when hitting someone.

You can check if its a bug by using a invisibility potion or that spell you can get after completing the `thiefs guild questline` that makes you invisible while crouched.

If you are doing all these steps,i just can't figure out while you are getting caught. Probably a Bug.

Comment: What does "Light Armor(5/5)" have to do with it?

Comment: If you have all pieces of light armor you dont make much noise. Robes dont make noise at all and heavy armor do produce much more noise. Im nor Talking about perks, but armor pieces.

Comment: Right, except that muffle takes care of that, and both heavy and light armor have perks that make them silent.

Comment: Conditioning Heavy Armor 70, Cushioned Heavy Armor weighs nothing and doesn't slow you down when worn

Slow you down is totally different of making no noise.

Comment: Weighs nothing = no noise.

Comment: Sorry, you are still incorrect.
No weight does not mean no noise. Refere here for the answer : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36801/does-the-conditioning-perk-improve-sneak-and-stamina

Do not post things that might confuse people

Comment: Agreed, no wieght doesn't mean no noise...

Answer (score -2):

Heavy armor:Makes a lot of noise on it own. If it is really heavy more noise such as Dragon Bone armor. Light armor: makes less noise and a lot lighter so (faster). Being able to kill quick is very good for someone like you. If you use a dagger UPGRADE ONE HANDED only straight up. Power attacks are good if you think a normal crouching attack will not kill this also enables a stealthy kill. UPGRADE SNEAK SKILL COMPLETELY! Dark Brother hood gloves and boots are very good as well, same with Astrids Blade of Woe. Hope this helps now go upgrade these two skills at the very being of the game with either person i became level 100 sneak and level 50 one handed in the first room in Helgan! P.S. you should try using two daggers at once also upgrade that on one handed!

Comment: Your answer does not seem to take into account the specifics of the question. The question already states that they have 100 sneak and relevant perks. Additionally your answer does not add anything that hasn't already been stated. If you agree with another answer, just upvote it.